# Typed Array assignment in F#

Tags: arrays, types, f#

Why doesn't this work?

```
open System
let ary = Array.create<Int16> 10
ary.[0] <- 42 // compiler error
printfn "%d" ary.[0] // compiler error
```

The error I get is something like:

The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding further type constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for `Array.create<'T>` is:

```
Array.create : int -> 'T -> 'T []
```

Currently you're only providing the first argument (number of elements to create) so `ary` is actually a function: `Int16 -> Int16 []`

You need to pass the second argument which is the value to use for the elements in the array:

```
let ary = Array.create<Int16> 10 0s
```

If you want the type's default value to be used for all the elements in the array (as it is in the above example) then you can use `Array.zeroCreate` as @Sehnsucht has pointed out

Comment: or use `Array.zeroCreate<Int16> 10`

Comment: Thank you! I need to get used to reading those compiler messages - especially getting used to those type signatures!

Comment: You don't need to supply a type argument for `create` as it will be inferred to be the type of the second argument (`0s`) .